# Limiting search results in SharePoint 2013 using search result source

Tags: 2013, search-results

currently my SharePoint site display search result from all web application.

I'm trying to create new search New result source for from site settings which will display results from current web application only.

Is is possible to do that?

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Create a result source from the Search service application were the web-application URL is included, like this:

```
{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople path:https://webapplicationurl.domain.com/*
```

('{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople' is from the default result source query to return everything but users.).